# Ruby Array, Hash, Integer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ice-cube

I am using a gem called `"ice_cube"`

When buliding a schedule i need to pass some integers into the .day() method like so:

```
schedule.add_recurrence_rule IceCube::Rule.weekly(1).day(1,2,3)
```

when i do this directly, it works. However, when i try to pass a variable that contains the integers into the .day() method is where I get lost.

tried this:

```
days = [1,2,3]

schedule.add_recurrence_rule IceCube::Rule.weekly(1).day(days)
```

it doesn't work. error i get is...

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `<' for [1, 2, 3]:Array):
```

Am i making a very obvious mistake?

How should i format my variable `days` so that it is accepted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to use the `splat` operator to expand the array into separate arguments (which then get combined into a single array in the `days` method probably):

```
days = [1,2,3]

schedule.add_recurrence_rule IceCube::Rule.weekly(self.every.to_i).day(*days)
```

Comment: Just what I was about to suggest, but shouldn't the splat be before the variable name like this: *days

Comment: I'll allow it :) Thank you very much. I have seen this around, mostly in rdoc's but have never paid much attention to it. You don't know something until you learn it! Thank you!

Comment: @Pete Haha, then I wish it was friday more often for me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
schedule.add_recurrence_rule IceCube::Rule.weekly(1).day(*days)
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response Dave. I admire the minimalism, but chose the other answer for obvious reasons. Have a nice weekend, thanks again!